# java filter stopped working in websphere

Tags: java, filter, websphere-7

I am implementing a filter in a Java application in WAS v7.0, and all of the sudden my filter stopped being invoked. I put together my code and web.xml as recommended by different sources and things were working, my filter was kicking off, as my debugging showed, but after I added a check in my code, my filter started being ignored.
I did compare the log that shows in the console with one I had saved when it was working and I observed that this line stopped appearing in the log:

[28-10-16 16:02:57:775 CLST] 0000001e webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Mensaje de servlet - [eIBS_R04M07#eibs_container_scotiachile.war]:.RequestLoggingFilter initialized

I have been running the app in debug mode, and I can see my filter simply doesn't get invoked at all, so I am guessing somehow it is like the module that deals with filters is not getting loaded in the server, to call it somehow.

Has anybody run into a situation like this? Is there anyway to check the server for this functionality? I am including my web.xml settings below, but as I said, everythg was working fine and all of the sudden it started ignoring everythg related to filters. Any help is highly appreciated

### WEB.XML

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>XSSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>XSSFilter.class</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
            <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>XSSFilter.class</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Why is your filter-name XSSFilter.class? should'nt it be just XSSFilter?

Comment: I found a post that asked to include it like that and to make sure the .class file were created in WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Joe I just changed what you highlighted and I am back in business! thanks a lot!